# Q: Excel add 6 months to a date if a cell has GOV

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to add 6 months to a date if a cell says "gov".

kind of if A1=gov then B1+6months

Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to change the date in B1, or do you want to return the date 6 months after B1 in a different cell?

Comment: You will need to clarify what you mean by "add 6 months". You can't just advance the month by 6: what date is 6 months after 31st December? You could advance 182 days or 26 weeks quite easily, but is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=IF(A1="GOV",DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)+6,DAY(B1)),B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: @Bandersnatch  ....................thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the first answer but shorter date manipulation function:

```
=IF(A1="GOV",EDATE(B1,6),B1)
```